# Поворот объекта к центу другого объекта в Unity3d C#

Tags: c#, unity3d

У меня есть сфера. У меня есть куб. Мне нужно ось(у) куба поворачивать к центру сферы. Как это реализовать?

Comment: ну например https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.LookAt.html

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Спасибо, а он повораивает но по оси Z, а мне нужна ось Y. Можете подсказать как сделать?

Comment: второй параметр - `worldUp Vector` specifying the upward direction. Разве не то, что нужно?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский. Понял. Тогда извиняюсь за глупый вопрос

Comment: @АлексейШиманский что-то я не могу врезатся как оно поворачивает обект. Пробовал по разному менять координаты но обект всяравно смотрит в сферу `transform.LookAt(target, new Vector3(x, y, z));` координаты менял по разному.

Comment: @Ezdrael По моему второй параметр передается для того чтобы указать как ориентировать объект чтобы после нацеливания у него верх совпадал с верхом в мировой системе координат.

Answer (score 1):

Нацелиться на объект проще всего при помощи http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.LookAt.html. При этом объект разворачивается осью `Z` по направлению к требуемой точке. Чтобы прицеливаться другой осью, например `Y` - можно нацелиться через `LookAt`, а потом сделать поворот объекта еще на `90` градусов вокруг оси `Х`.

Но гораздо проще возьмите свой объект  и поместите основной объект внутрь пустого объекта развернув его в нем так, чтобы его ось `Y` совпадала с осью `Z` пустого объекта. Ну а дальше крутите родителя через `LookAt` без всяких лишних телодвижений.